# Using onclick event with select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to load with ajax the options of a select after onclick

I tried using onclick and click functions of jquery but doesn't work

```js
$(".myselect").on("click", function() {
  let thisv = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    url: "cargar_select_plazas",
    dataType: "JSON",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      some: data
    },
    success: function(r) {
      let html = "";
      for (let x in r) {
        html += `<option value="` + r[x].theid + `">` + r[x].thenameproduct + `</option>`;
      }
      $(thisv).html(html);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control custom-select myselect">
</select>
```

Comment: Define not work. Is the onclick function not triggered? Is there any error on console?

Comment: place `console.log('entered')` before `let thisv = $(this);`, `console.log(r)` before `let html = "";` and `console.log(x)` before `html +='<option value="'+r[x].theid+'">'+r[x].thenameproduct+'</option>';`. Also, check out the proper use of single quotes when adding the option strings. Share the results

Comment: The select dropdown will be displayed before the AJAX call completes, so the user won't see the options that you added to the menu.

Comment: The whole reason to put backticks around the string is so you *don't* have to use concatenation to insert variables.

Comment: the ajax call return the data that i want, the problem is, with onclick event is not working on first time i need to double click on a select to work, here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/dr52p9en/

Comment: @JuanPerez It can't work as you want. Read my comment above.

Comment: You need to update the select before the user clicks on it so they'll see the updated options.

Comment: Do it in whatever function sets `data`.

Comment: @Barmar the reason that i would load data after click on a select is because i have a lot of select option and for not loading all selects i want just load the option of a select that the user will need, https://imgur.com/wCBsl27.png

Comment: Sorry, but it's just not possible. Clicking on the select shows the menu immediately, it doesn't wait for the AJAX request to finish.

Comment: When working with asynchronous operations like AJAX, it's a good idea to imagine that it takes several seconds for the server to respond. Would you expect the browser to block opening the menu for 5 seconds?

Comment: yes, i would expect that, the onclick event not work well with select? i load the data that i want but not in the first click

Comment: This approach is extremely, extremely, extremely bad UX - wanting to block the select box until it is populated, just because 'have a lot of select option and for not loading all selects' - are they in the order of hundreds? thousands? would it bloat the markup so much that it would cause performance issues? or is it a case of overthinking and micro-optimization that mostly bites you in the ass, without actually adding any benefit?

Comment: Would simply recommend : load the options when the page loads, if you don't want to include them statically within your markup - if that is not satisfactory, put the whole form within a modal, with a spinner, so the user has some visual feedback that the content is loading, and serve all 'heavy' form fields at once. Beyond that, don't block the users actions, or you will find that most users will simply consider that the whole website/app is poorly written and optimized, and will leave without a positive memory to come back to. Don't shoot yourself in the foot. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To my knowledge jQuery doesn't support *click* event on *select* element
- Putting    the *select* in a *div* and binding *click* event on that *div* would be a
  workaround
- In these approaches, however, the request will take time to complete during which the user won't be able 
  to see updated options.
- Of the top of my head, a better way to do it would be to bind it to *focus* event, handler 
  for which would first show a loader, then complete and process the request and options and finally remove 
  the loader.